# updating the extent automatically in the print composer

Tags: qgis, cartography, printing

Just started using QGIS (after trying what I need to in GRASS).

Using the Print Composer, I've put down a map which is based on the map in my map canvas, which is what I'll want to print. Then put down a few logos as well, which need to be printed on the map.

Now, the people who will eventually be using this map will be panning and zooming around merrily on the map canvas, then expect it to print what is on the map canvas, as well as the logos. Using a saved Print Composer file here will be fine.

Trouble is, can the Print Composer automatically update it's extents to match the map canvas? If not, I don't think it's a HUGE problem - I'll just tell them to use the "Set to map canvas extent" button, but it would be nice if it could do this automatically.

Comment: There does not appear to be a composer auto refresh option.

Comment: Thought not. Any chance of being able to start the composer through a python script (which could be attached to a button) and then have that same script feed the current extent into the composer? Bit of a trek...

Comment: I'm sure this plugin could be written, since this is a different question you should create a new one for it.  Here is the map composer API page, http://qgis.org/api/classQgsComposerMap.html

Comment: Relevant topic that should be suggested developed for a future version of QGIS

Comment: Update.  A better workaround instead of using "Set to map canvas extent" is using the "Sync composer with Map"-plugin. It´s not a solution to your question, though.